# React Native CLI giving me an error when trying to run app

Tags: reactjs, command-line-interface, native

So I have a project where someone has asked me to help them with there rreact native pp. I have used react native with expo. But this is the first time with cli. I have followed the install directions as shown here.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?platform=android&package-manager=yarn

I was able to create a simple sample app. I was able to run this app both on ios and android. Again following the steps that mentioned.

Then I got to download the clients app. Using a git clone. I am able to get the app on my desktop and this is where I now run into issues. Following the same steps.

For iOS:
- When trying to run yarn install I get that it does install and updates.
- Then yarn start I get the following error, This is done in the main file directory. After doing yarn install

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Desktop/<app name>/node_modules (25ms)
Loading dependency graph...
error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported (appears to be a node issue)
```

```
-
```

I have also tried to do the pods install inside the ios folder and it appears to also install

For Android:
- When opening the file in Android Studio. I see that I have no run config.
- To fix the no run config, I create one for an android app. But the file has no module

Here is the react native doctor results:

```
⠋ Running diagnostics...warn Command failed with exit code 1: ruby -e require "Bundler"; gemfile = Bundler::Definition.build("Gemfile", nil, {}); version = gemfile.ruby_version.engine_versions.join(", "); begin; gemfile.validate_runtime!; rescue Bundler::GemfileNotFound; puts "No Gemfile"; exit 1; rescue Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch; puts "Bundle invalid Ruby"; STDERR.puts version; exit 2; rescue => e; STDERR e.message; exit 3; else; puts "Ok"; STDERR.puts version; end
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:32:in `build': /Users/radiospirits/Desktop/radiospirits/Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ✓ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode

Android
 ✖ Adb - No devices and/or emulators connected. Please create emulator with Android Studio or connect Android device.
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: 28.0.3, 30.0.3, 34.0.0
   - Version supported: 26.0.2
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

iOS
 ✓ Xcode - Required for building and installing your app on iOS
 ✓ Ruby
 ✓ CocoaPods - Required for installing iOS dependencies
 ✓ ios-deploy - Required for installing your app on a physical device with the CLI
 ✖ .xcode.env - File to customize Xcode environment
```

Also if I try doing :
- npx react-native run-ios This gets an error too. So I have had to run everything in the IDE

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/xxxxxxxx/node_modules (23ms)
Found Xcode workspace xxxxxxxxx.xcworkspace
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find instruments 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 17664: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH

Command failed: xcrun instruments -s
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find instruments 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 17664: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

When doing this for android I get

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/xxxxxx/node_modules (24ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.20'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

If I try to run the app in Android Studio? I get a gradle is out dated. I upgrade and then am unable to sync the gradle.

Everything that I did for the simple sample app is not working now on the live app.

Expecting the app to run. Running on a mac.